# Interpolation FIR filter Remez design criteria

Tags: filter-design, finite-impulse-response, interpolation, resampling

I want to upsample an audio signal by a factor of 8.

The technique I was going to use was to upsample by zero stuffing and then interopolate using a low pass anti-aliasing FIR filter designed using the Remez exchange algorithm.

**My question is: what are the design constraints for the Remez algorithm?**

My initial thoughts are:

If I have an initial sampling rate of 44100Hz then my new sampling rate will be 352800‬Hz. When I zero stuff, my spectral content in the range 0-22050Hz will be folder around the new upsampled Nyquist of 176400Hz in the range ‭154350‬-176400Hz.‬ So I have the following constraints:

- Sample rate: 352800‬Hz
- Pass band: 0-22050Hz (0dB)
- Stop band: 154350-176400Hz (-120dB)

This does not produce an very good filter, so my assumption that I only have one spectral image folded around 176400Hz must be incorrect.

Comment: you usually wouldn't use a remez design for a simple low-pass filter like this. Also, -120 dB is probably way more attenuation than you need. Then, your first spectral image is the original signal spectrum (-22.05 kHz to +22.05 kHz) repeated around 44.1 kHz, so your transition width is far, far too wide. I think the best advice I can give here is: Make a drawing of your spectrum after inserting the zeros, and carefully label the axes. Make sure you realize that your spectrum is symmetric to 0 Hz, because your signal is real-valued.

Comment: (so, yes, your assumption is incorrect, but I'm not sure where that assumption comes from – you don't explain that. The easiest way to discuss this, as said, is probably by looking at the spectrum you'd draw.)

Comment: @MarcusMüller, I took the information from this paper: http://lavryengineering.com/pdfs/lavry-sampling-oversampling-imaging-aliasing.pdf where it shows the spectrum fold around the new Nyquist (page 3).

Comment: Really not quite sure how *you* apply this to *your* interpolation problem - can you **really** draw the spectrum of the zero-stuffed signal for us?

Comment: Any qualified lowpass filter will work for your interpolation problem. This of course includes the Remez (Parks-McClellan Equiripple) FIR filter too. What's your allowed / required filter order ?

Comment: @Fat32, the filter order could be anything i.e. I can use 1000+ taps.

Comment: @MarcusMüller, I've done some spectral analysis of what happens to sine waves when they are zero stuffed. It looks like the spectral images occur after 22.05kHz up to 176400Hz, so my transition band is the problem.

Comment: exactly. to repeat myself the third time: Draw the spectrum like it is *before* filtering. Add that drawing to your question, so that we can help you get things right!